# exc_bad_access even with starship example project

Tags: ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create my first iOS game, but I have a weird problem. When I try to launch my game on device, I get a "exc_bad_access". At first, I thought I was deleting something, or doing something wrong, but after great headaches, and figure out it cannot be something in my code, so I tried to create a vanilla SpriteKIT project (the one with rotating starships).

On Simulator all it's ok (as for my game), but, once run on device, the application crash with an exc_bad_access error on main. The problems seems to present whenever a "[self addChild: node]" it's called.

Any idea??? I'm running iOS 7.1 on my device and using Xcode 5.

Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself** (aka "post relevant sections of the code that fails"). Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: The problem is replicable creating a new SpriteKit game on XCode. However I found the problem. I created the project on Xcode beta 6, that introduce a new kind of file (.sks). Probably the feature is not ready, because cause app crash when it start on device. I deleted the file and passed to xcode5/ios7-style for creating new scene.

Thank you for your answer.